# Magento 2.3.0 Overriding footer.phtml

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.0, template-override

I am trying to override Magento 2 **footer.phtml,** with my custom html footer, I have tried almost everything but still no success, I even tried the below:

You can overwrite the existing templates by copying them into your theme and making changes to the template files.

So copy these two files:

> vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/header.phtml
>   vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/templates/html/footer.phtml

Into your theme:

> app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/header.phtml
>   app/design/frontend/VENDOR/THEME/Magento_Theme/templates/html/footer.phtml

Comment: **The code seems ok. Please ensure that  theme is installed properly at the system.**

Comment: @Amit Bera  Theme installed properly but custom files not loadin at all, please help guys...

Comment: Have you configured your theme in admin please ensure it

Comment: Theme configured, I am halfway my theme styling aswell, still nothing on loading the footer file.

Comment: Maybe this is obvious but have you cleared the cache and ran `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` ?

Comment: Still no change @Aerno Vande Cappelle